# Drawing outside footer area

Tags: header-footer, tikz-node

I've been working on a footer that renders the page number inside a tikz node. A MWE is:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,pagesize=auto,hidelinks,cleardoublepage=empty,parskip]{scrbook}

\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=7in,margin=1in,heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{tikz}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyfoot[r]
{%
    {%
        \tikz%
        {%
            \node (a) [circle,text=black,draw,fill=black!5,inner xsep=1.5pt,inner ysep=1.5pt,outer sep=0pt]%
            {%
                num
            };%
            \node (b) [left of=a,node distance=6cm,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] {};%
            \node (c) [right of=a,node distance=1cm,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] {};%
            \draw (a.west) -- (b.center);%
            \draw (a.east) -- (c.center);%
        }%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
    Whatever
\end{document}
```

This renders as:

[image]

"num" is just a stand-in for my page number, to avoid complicating the MWE.

I would like to extend the lines either side of the node so that they reach all the way to the page edges, but I can't figure out how. If I increase the gaps between the nodes too much, the number node gets pushed off to the right. For example, if I increase the gap between nodes *a* and *b* to 10cm, I get:

[image]

If I increase it more, then the number gets pushed off the right of the page entirely.

How can extend the lines either side of the node to the page edges without affecting the position of the number node?

Comment: Have you tried "remember picture" and "overlay" from tikz?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I have not, and frankly I'm not sure how I would go about doing so.

Comment: I don't have access to a computer at the moment. Just an advice, google for "tikz absolute positioning remember picture". It's a very powerful approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## MWE

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,pagesize=auto,hidelinks,cleardoublepage=empty,parskip]{scrbook}

\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=7in,margin=1in,heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{tikz}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyfoot[r]
{%
    {%
        \tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=(a.south)]%
        {%
            \draw(0,0-|current page.west)--(0,0-|current page.east) node(a)[circle,text=black,draw,fill=black!5,inner xsep=1.5pt,inner ysep=1.5pt,outer sep=0pt,pos=.8]%
            {%
                num
            };%
        }%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
    Whatever
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks, but unless I'm missing something, this does not solve my problem. I want the line to extend to the **full width** of the page, and if I replace your `linewidth` with `paperwidth`, I get exactly the same behavior as described in my question (output is pushed out to the right).

Comment: @KentBoogaart: See my edit? You need to compile twice to get the correct output.

Comment: Nice! That's exactly the effect I'm after - thanks very much.

Comment: @KentBoogaart: Glad I could help `;)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an additional suggestion using package `scrlayer-scrpage` which is part of the KOMA-Script bundle:

```
 \documentclass[fontsize=11pt,parskip]{scrbook}
\usepackage[
  paperheight=9in,paperwidth=7in,
  margin=1in,heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm,
  showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ofoot*{
  \hspace*{1cm}%
  \smash{\makebox[0pt][c]{\tikz{
    \node(a)[circle,draw,fill=black!5,inner sep=1.5pt,outer sep=0pt]{num};
    \draw(a-|-\paperwidth,0)--(a)--(a-|\paperwidth,0);
  }}}
  \hspace*{1cm}%
}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was looking for something like this, but I'd like the page number a bit further down. How would i manage that? Also, what are the `\hspace*{1cm}`s for?

Comment: @FaheemMitha You could use option `baseline` for the `tikz` environment, eg. `\tikz[baseline=(a.base)]{...}`. Another possibility is `\raisbox`, eg. `\smash{\raisebox{-10pt}{...}}` or you could move down the layers for the footer. If you remove the `\hspace*{1cm}` the  page numbers would be aligned with the outer edge of the text area.

Comment: I tried `\setlength\footskip{100pt}`, which did seem to move the page numbers down. But I'll try your other suggestions as well.